# Using pd.ExcelWriter to write many dataframes to a single Excel workbook for VBA manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have over 60 dataframes to write to an excel template. My intention is to paste all these to various named ranges via vba once all df's are exported.

```
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df['state'].value_counts().to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=5, startcol=0, na_rep=0, header=True, index=True, merge_cells= True)
```

This works as expected but when I look to add the two following df's I get AttributeErrors

```
df_Shape = df.shape[0]
display(df_Shape)
df_Shape.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0, startcol=0, na_rep=0, header=True, index=True, merge_cells= True)

4802
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

df_Start_Date = df['rfq_create_date_time'].min()
display(df_Start_Date)
df_Start_Date.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=3, startcol=0, na_rep=0, header=True, index=True, merge_cells= True)

Timestamp('2018-05-01 06:55:25')
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

excel_writer.save()
```

Is there additional work for single celled dataframes when using .to_excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df_Shape` is a shape of `df`
`df_Start_Date` is a time

They're not `pd.DataFrame` objects, thus they don't have method `.to_excel`

**EDIT**:
You can create new dataframe with necessary statistics and write it to the same sheet:

```
stats = [{
    "len": df.shape[0],
    "min_time": df["rfq_create_date_time"].min()
}, ] # List of dictionaries, to have a row, not column

with pd.ExcelWriter(path) as excel_writer:
    pd.DataFrame(stats).to_excel(excel_writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=0)
    df.to_excel(excel_writer, startrow=3, sheet_name='Sheet1'))
```

Comment: Are there alternative to get the number of rows in a df and min/max values ehich are objects?

Comment: Quite a few exports are single values which are a result of df.count(), .mean(0 etc

Comment: @PeterLucas I've added the code that might help you

Comment: Good one! @Kopytok I got a path error but I'll can figure that out. Outputs values if I just write the list